# How to check if a TRUSTEE is me

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I'm using the [**`GetSecurityInfo`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446654(v=vs.85).aspx) funtion to get my own process's *Discretional Access Control List* (DACL):

```
PACL oldAcl;
Pointer se;
GetSecurityInfo(GetCurrentProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 
      null, null, ref oldAcl, nil, ref se);
```

And then i can use the [**`GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446638(v=vs.85).aspx) to crack open the ACL to get at it's list of *Access Control Entries* (ACE) inside:

```
UInt32 nCount;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS[] list;
GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl(oldAcl, ref nCount, ref list);
```

I can go through the list of three entries on my process:

- STACKOVERFLOW\ian (S-1-5-21-6198258843-697258998-2146844275-1109) [SidTypeUser]

  - Grant Access

    - 0x00010000 DELETE
    - 0x00020000 READ_CONTROL
    - 0x00040000 WRITE_DAC
    - 0x00080000 WRITE_OWNER
    - 0x00100000 SYNCHRONIZE
    - ...
    - 0x00000008 PROCESS_VM_OPERATION
    - 0x00000010 PROCESS_VM_READ
    - 0x00000020 PROCESS_VM_WRITE
- NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (S-1-5-18) [SidTypeWellKnownGroup]

  - Grant Access

    - 0x00010000 DELETE
    - 0x00020000 READ_CONTROL
    - 0x00040000 WRITE_DAC
    - 0x00080000 WRITE_OWNER
    - 0x00100000 SYNCHRONIZE
    - ...
    - 0x00000008 PROCESS_VM_OPERATION
    - 0x00000010 PROCESS_VM_READ
    - 0x00000020 PROCESS_VM_WRITE
- NT AUTHORITY\LogonSessionId_0_20117843 (S-1-5-5-0-20117843) [SidType_11]

  - Grant Access

    - 0x00020000 READ_CONTROL
    - 0x00100000 SYNCHRONIZE
    - 0x00000010 PROCESS_VM_READ
    - 0x00000400 PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION
    - 0x00001000 PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION

I now want to go through and update the DACL for the process (which of course i'm allowed to do since i have `WRITE_DACL` - and because i'm the Owner, [which means i implicitly have `WRITE_DACL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

But i only want to re-write *access control entries* that apply to *"me"*.

In this case there happen to be three **Trustees**:

- S-1-5-21-6198258843-697258998-2146844275-1109 *(user me)*
- S-1-5-18 *(user LocalSystem - not me)*
- S-1-5-5-0-20117843 *(group LoginSession - me)*

Trustees are presented to us as a [`TRUSTEE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379636(v=vs.85).aspx) object (note, not all of which have an SID). I know from experience that i *am* two of those trustees; but not the third.

Is there a function that i can use to compare *"me"* against a **`TRUSTEE`**?

```
Boolean DoIMatchThisTrustee(TRUSTEE trustee)
{

}
```

### Why am i doing this?

No reason. I'm removing `PROCESS_VM_READ`, `PROCESS_VM_WRITE`, and `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` from myself on my own process.

Comment: you need compare are some *Sid* is (enabled) member of your token. you can use for this `CheckTokenMembership` - so open process token, duplicate it (for make an impersonation token) and then in loop query *Sids* from dacl with this api. as alternative you can first get list of groups in your process token and yourself walk by this list for every *Sid*.in any case i think more easy and effective use `GetKernelObjectSecurity` instead `GetSecurityInfo` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RbMm's comment reminded me that i already knew the answer somewhere deep in my brain: **`CheckTokenMembeship`**:

```
//Get the ACL on the process
PACL oldAcl;
Pointer se;

GetSecurityInfo(GetCurrentProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 
      null, null, ref oldAcl, nil, ref se); //allocates memory into se, which we must LocalFree later
//oldAcl is a pointer to inside the se blob


//Crack open the ACL, to feast on the entries inside
UInt32 nCount;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS[] list;
GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl(oldAcl, ref nCount, ref list); //allocates memory into list, which we must localFree later


//the flags i want to remove me from having    
DWORD removeFlags = PROCESS_VM_READ || PROCESS_VM_WRITE || PROCESS_VM_OPERATION;

//Go through the list, looking for entries that are "me"
for (EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea in list)
{
   if (ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm != TRUSTEE_IS_SID) 
      continue;

   BOOL isMember;
   CheckTokenMembership(0, PSID(ea.Trustee.ptstrName), out isMember);

   if (!isMember)
      continue;

   //Remove the permissions
   ea.grfAccessPermissions = ea.grfAccessPermissions && (!removeFlags);
   aclUpdateNeeded = true;
}


//write the new DACL
SetEntriesInAcl(nCount, list, null, out newAcl); //allocates a new acl
SetSecurityInfo(GetCurrentProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 
      null, null, newAcl, null); //apply the new acl

LocalFree(list); //free the memory allocated by GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl
LocalFree(se); //free the memory allocated by GetSecurityInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

you actually want check *Discretional Access Control List* (DACL) for Sids which is "me" - so enabled members of your process token.

To determine whether a SID is enabled in a token we can use `CheckTokenMembership` function.

use `GetSecurityInfo` not the best choice i think, much better use `GetKernelObjectSecurity` here. however you can check and trustees if want ("note, not all of which have an SID" - this is in general case, but in case *DACL* you will got only `TRUSTEE_IS_SID` trustees). code can be next:

```
void Test()
{
    HANDLE hToken, hImpToken;

    if (OpenProcessToken(NtCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken))
    {
        BOOL fOk = DuplicateToken(hToken, ::SecurityIdentification, &hImpToken);

        CloseHandle(hToken);

        if (fOk)
        {
            ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 256;

            static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;
            PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
            union {
                PVOID buf;
                PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
            };

            do 
            {
                if (cb < rcb)
                {
                    cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                }

                if (GetKernelObjectSecurity(NtCurrentProcess(), DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD, cb, &rcb))
                {
                    BOOL bPresent, bDefault;

                    union {
                        PACL Acl;
                        PBYTE pb;
                        PACE_HEADER pah;
                        PACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE paaa;
                    };

                    if (GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, &bPresent, &Acl, &bDefault) && bPresent && Acl)
                    {
                        CheckSidsInAcl(Acl);

                        if (USHORT AceCount = Acl->AceCount)
                        {
                            Acl++;

                            do 
                            {
                                if (pah->AceType == ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE)
                                {
                                    BOOL IsMember;
                                    if (CheckTokenMembership(hImpToken, &paaa->SidStart, &IsMember))
                                    {
                                        PWSTR sz;
                                        if (ConvertSidToStringSid(&paaa->SidStart, &sz))
                                        {
                                            DbgPrint("%x %S\n", IsMember, sz);
                                            LocalFree(sz);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        GetLastError();
                                    }
                                }

                            } while (pb += pah->AceSize, --AceCount);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

            } while (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

            CloseHandle(hImpToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is always TRUSTEE_IS_SID? I can't find any information about this on MSDN. I assume it could also be TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID.

Comment: @Anders - i don't know and don't use this. here question in method after we got *DACL* and final target. i direct yourself walk by *ACE* list in *ACL* and check are sid from ace with type `ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE` existing in token. and ignore other ACE types (if present). `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl` the simply convert ACE list to `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` array. `ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE` ace converted to `TRUSTEE_IS_SID` trustee. i simply ignore in this code ace of other types( `ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE` -> `TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID`)

Comment: @Anders - really you right - my code need be extended for process not only `ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE` but `ACCESS_ALLOWED_CALLBACK_ACE_TYPE`, `ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE` (not sure how check this type for not ignore objec - format SD with this ace only and call `AccessCheck` ?) however if we speak about process dacl - this is extremely rarely case (never view at all this ace types in process dacl)

Comment: so for be clear - use `ACE` list or `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` (which is build from `ACE` list) - no matter. your question can reformulate as - how do i know that only `ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE` (from allowed ace types) will be. don't know but and not assume. simply in code skip another ACE types. question - are need extend code for handle this (and in case `ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE` check only Sid from ace and ignore ObjectType or ?)

Comment: The actual question is titled "How to check if a TRUSTEE is me" and you don't touch on that at all in your answer. It is a interesting question (IMHO) and the TRUSTEE and other APIs added in 2000 & XP were added for a reason, to get most people to stop messing with the ACL and ACEs directly.

Comment: @Anders - yes, i reformulate question based on OP target how i understand it. target not exactly `TRUSTEE` (this is instrument only) but modification of process DACL (*removing ..*). `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl` simply convert ACE list (ACE variable size struct) to fixed size `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` array. work with one or second form here no matter really . here you ask good question - how process (need ?) `ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE` or `TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID` (different form of the same)

Comment: i be say - not problem work with `ACE` or `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` (`TRUSTEE`). by fact the same by sense. problem decide how check "me" in nonstandard case `ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE` - are this ACE (or trustee from this ace) give some access to token ("me"). for be full correct - need ask system - so build SD with this single ACE in DACL and call `AccessCheck[ByType]`. really this and do `CheckTokenMembership` internal, which take on self most job. but in case `ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE` need direct call `AccessCheck[ByType]`. at all not sure are all this is need(final target?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any functions to compare nor normalize a TRUSTEE.

The ACEs in a ACL always store a SID (as far as I know) so it is probably safe to assume that the TRUSTEE will be a TRUSTEE_IS_*SID form when you get it from a ACL.

```
PSID GetSID(const TRUSTEE&t)
{
    if (TRUSTEE_IS_SID == t.TrusteeForm) return (PSID) t.ptstrName;
    if (TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID == t.TrusteeForm) return ((OBJECTS_AND_SID*)t.ptstrName)->pSid;
    return NULL;
}

bool DoIMatchThisTrustee(TRUSTEE&t)
{
  PSID tsid = GetSID(t);
  PSID mysid = GetMySid(); // From process/thread token or somewhere else
  return tsid && EqualSid(tsid, mysid);
}
```

If you don't want to assume then you can use `LookupAccountName` on the string forms to get a SID.

If for whatever reason you don't want to lookup any strings you can do things NT4 style and work with the ACL directly. Call `GetAce` to enumerate the ACL and use something like this:

```
PSID GetAllowedSID(const ACE_HEADER&ah)
{
    switch(ah.AceType)
    {
    case ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: return (PSID) &((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)&ah)->SidStart;
    case ACCESS_ALLOWED_CALLBACK_ACE_TYPE: return (PSID) &((ACCESS_ALLOWED_CALLBACK_ACE*)&ah)->SidStart;
    case ACCESS_ALLOWED_CALLBACK_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE: return (PSID) &((ACCESS_ALLOWED_CALLBACK_OBJECT_ACE*)&ah)->SidStart;
    case ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE_TYPE: return (PSID) &((ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT_ACE*)&ah)->SidStart;
    default: return NULL;
    }
}
```

If you are doing this to increase security you might want to do things the other way around and only allow "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" and "BUILTIN\Administrators" these rights.

Whether or not the logon session is "you" is debatable but you cannot compare the full SID to find out, just the SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY+[SECURITY_LOGON_IDS_RID parts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_leblanc/2007/07/29/logon-id-sids/).

Comment: `PSID mysid = GetMySid();` - really process (token) have not single sid but group of sids (token groups) and if sid from allowed ace in this group(and enabled) - token is owner of object (so have special access as owner)

Comment: @RbMm GetMySid() would ask for GetTokenInformation(TokenUser) most likely. Really depends on what the definition of "me" is.

Comment: yes, but i based on OP where he say logon sid marked as me - *S-1-5-5-0-20117843 (group LoginSession - me)* also by sense need check token groups but not token user sid (he can simply not present it dacl at all). for example in elevated process 3 ace - 'Administrators'(`S-1-5-32-544`), `S-1-5-18 'SYSTEM'` and logon sid. but process user sid not 'Administrators' but some S-1-5-21-***. so i think check by  token user sid is incorrect by sense

Comment: "me" how i understand question - is ACE entry, which give some access to object for current process

Comment: Blocking administrators is pointless, they can take ownership. Blocking the users SID does make sense, it will prevent other applications at the same integrity level from injecting. I assume we are talking about normal applications running @ <= Medium IL. Elevated processes can probably debug and do whatever they want no matter what you do as long as you are not a protected process.

Comment: i simply try say that if look for elevated process dacl and token - i view next concrete case - dacl have allowed ace for *administrators*, *system*, and logonsession sid. but process token user sid not *administrators* but some user sid (S-1-5-21-...). if based on this check - process dacl at al not have "me" sids. i nothing say about sense something disable or enable in DACL. simply note about tokenuser sid. which can not present in process dacl at all. if say about access - check by token groups but not tokenuser